# Upload file using wt

Tags: wt

I am new to WT, i am trying the upload file example .
The code works fine when i click the send button the file progress bar runs to 100% but i am not sure where it is uploaded ? can we define to upload in certain path..

```
class HelloApplication: public WApplication {
public:
    HelloApplication(const WEnvironment& env);

private:

    WPushButton *uploadButton;
    Wt::WFileUpload *fu;

    void greet();
};

HelloApplication::HelloApplication(const WEnvironment& env) :
        WApplication(env) {
    root()->addStyleClass("container");
    setTitle("Hello world");       // application title

    fu = new Wt::WFileUpload(root());
    fu->setFileTextSize(50); // Set the maximum file size to 50 kB.
    fu->setProgressBar(new Wt::WProgressBar());
    fu->setMargin(10, Wt::Right);

    // Provide a button to start uploading.
    uploadButton = new Wt::WPushButton("Send", root());
    uploadButton->setMargin(10, Wt::Left | Wt::Right);

    // Upload when the button is clicked.

    uploadButton->clicked().connect(this, &HelloApplication::greet);
}

void HelloApplication::greet() {
    fu->upload();
    uploadButton->disable();

}

WApplication *createApplication(const WEnvironment& env) {

    return new HelloApplication(env);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return WRun(argc, argv, &createApplication);
}
```

Comment: What have you found out so far and why was it not helpful?

Comment: I am not sure where the files are uploading ?

Comment: _What have you found out so far and why was it not helpful?_ Have you looked in the manuals already?

Comment: There is no documentation about where do the files will be uploaded or something like that. I read this alreadyhttp://www.webtoolkit.eu/widgets/forms/file-upload.. Can you direct to some documentation if you know?

Comment: @phresnel I am not copying the example from the site and asking you help. I tried the documentation i looked in the code and it was not helpful thats why i am here.And as stated i am new to WT

Answer (score 4):

A WFileUpload will fire a signal (uploaded()) when the file is completed. Then look at spoolFileName() to get the filename of the file on your local disk. Listen on fileTooLarge() too, since it will inform you that the upload failed.

The manual of WFileUpload comes with a lot of information and a code example:
http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WFileUpload.html

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old post but I also had issues and the question wasn't quite answered (specifically the **uploadedFiles** function that is needed to read the contents of the file)

In your constructor (i.e. the HelloApplication::HelloApplication function) add this to react to the fileUploaded signal:

```
uploadButton->uploaded().connect(this, &HelloApplication::fileUploaded);
```

Then add a function like this to read the contents of the file:

```
void HelloApplication::fileUploaded() {
    //The uploaded filename
    std::string mFilename = fu->spoolFileName(); 

    //The file contents
    std::vector<Wt::Http::UploadedFile> mFileContents = fu->uploadedFiles();

    //The file is temporarily stored in a file with location here
    std::string mContents;
    mContents=mFileContents.data()->spoolFileName();

    //Do something with the contents here
    //Either read in the file or copy it to use it

    //return
    return;
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else redirected here.